# G++ compiles wrong STL code

Tags: stl, g++

I guess I've found a G++ bug but I'm not sure. I cannot explain it. The compile shouldn't pass BAD code but it does. g++-4.5 and g++4.6 -std=c++0x pass this code without any warning.

As is the compile thinks that pointer to Bar object is Bar object itself.
I'm crazy. I spent many hours to get the bug. Is there any technique to protect from this kind of bug?

Bad code gives:

```
 g++-4.6 for_stackoverflow.cpp && ./a.out
 address of bar in main()   0xbff18fc0
 Foo 0x9e80008      Bar     0xbff18fec
 Foo 0x9e80028      Bar     0xbff18fec
 Foo 0x9e80048      Bar     0xbff18fec
 end
```

Source code:

```
     #include <iostream>
     #include <list>
     #include <iomanip>
     #include <algorithm>

     #define BAD

     using namespace std;

     class Bar;

     class Foo {
     public:
       virtual void tick(Bar & b) {
         cout << "Foo " << this << "      Bar " << setw(14) << (&b) << endl;
       }    
     };

     class Bar : public list<Foo*> {
     };

     int main() {
       Bar bar;
       cout << "address of bar in main()   " << &bar << endl;
       bar.push_back(new Foo());
       bar.push_back(new Foo());
       bar.push_back(new Foo());
     #ifdef GOOD
       for_each(bar.begin(), bar.end(), bind2nd(mem_fun(&Foo::tick), bar));
     #elif defined(BAD)
       for_each(bar.begin(), bar.end(), bind2nd(mem_fun(&Foo::tick), &bar));
     #else
     #error "define GOOD xor BAD"
     #endif
       cout << "end" << endl;
       return 0;
     }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`bind2nd` is declared as:

```
template <class Fn, class T>
binder2nd<Fn> bind2nd(const Fn&, const T&);
```

This means that the type `T` is deduced, in this case as `Bar *`.

On my system it's implemented as:

```
template<typename _Operation, typename _Tp>
inline binder2nd<_Operation>
bind2nd(const _Operation& __fn, const _Tp& __x)
{
  typedef typename _Operation::second_argument_type _Arg2_type;
  return binder2nd<_Operation>(__fn, _Arg2_type(__x));
}
```

To see why that would compile consider:

```
class Bar {};

int main() {
  Bar *b = 0;
  typedef const Bar& type;
  const type t = type(b);
}
```

which seems to be the real problem and does compile with g++, because [it's basically a `reinterpret_cast`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8806931/168175).

The simplest workaround is changing it to use `boost::bind` (or `std::bind` for C++11):

```
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
```

...

```
boost::bind(mem_fun(&Foo::tick), _1, &bar)
```

or a lambda function *does* give the error you'd expect to see.

Comment: As far I understood a type of the argument of bind2nd is inferred from the type of a real argument and then it is sharply converted to another without any checking and care.  This is genuine pitfall :(.    Like as follows  char x;  float f;  f = *((float *)(void *)&x);

Comment: @DaneelS.Yaitskov - I'm not too clear why the standard requires it to be `type(x)` instead of `static_cast<type>(x)`, but this seems likely to be one of the reasons that lead to `std::bind1st`/`std::bind2nd` being deprecated in favour of `std::bind` in C++11