# Typedef const reference from a pointer

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is it allowed to cast a pointer to a reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5924248/why-is-it-allowed-to-cast-a-pointer-to-a-reference)

Why does this compile:

```
class Bar {};

int main() {
  Bar i;
  Bar *b = &i;
  typedef const Bar& type;
  type t = type(b);
}
```

G++ ([4.5](http://www.ideone.com/huvDG), 4.7 snapshots), [Comeau](http://www.comeaucomputing.com/tryitout/) and MSVC all are happy but warn about unused variables.

What does the compiler think it means? Is it UB? Why isn't it an error?

I think it should be an error because I've accidentally made a `Bar*` into `const Bar&` without dereferencing or crazy casts. I thought every part of this was completely safe.

Comment: please reduce it to *minimal* code, e.g. remove `const` from `const type t`.

Comment: Maybe you should also write why you think it should be an error?

Comment: I get this: `warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules`. And the more appropriate `const type t(b);` is indeed an error. But you're right, why is this being dereferenced automatically?

Comment: @ronag: Clearly, you shouldn't be able to initialise a `Bar const&` from a `Bar*`. Also the `const type` shouldn't exist, but I think `const` gets ignored for type aliases anyway.

Comment: @ronag - I've elaborated on where I think there's a problem.

Comment: Why do you think a C-style cast should produce a compiler error? `int * p = 0; float const & t = (float const &) p;` will compile as well. It's C-style cast.

Comment: @AzzA: And that's a meaningless and unhelpful assertion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Author did a C-style cast and asked why compiler compiled it. C-style cast can cast, basically, anything to anything and C++ compiler is REQUIRED to let through, because it's required to compile C (at least, with casting). `double (*p)( void *, int, long double ) = 0; char * const & t = ( char * const & )p;` is, probably, meaningless, but it will compile!

Comment: @AzzA `T(v)` isn't legal C for any type `T`, which was the source of my confusion.

Comment: @awoodland In this context, `T(v)` is treated by compiler as `(T)v` - C-style cast, nothing more, nothing less. It's just that C++ compiler, naturally, allows this syntax, since it in the spirit of C++ class syntax: `A a; B b = B( a );`, provided there is constructor of `B::B( A const & );` sort... Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A C-style cast tries different C++ cast types in turn:

> `[C++11: 5.4/5]:` **The conversions performed by**
>
> - a `const_cast` (5.2.11),
> - a `static_cast` (5.2.9),
> - a `static_cast` followed by a `const_cast`,
> - **a `reinterpret_cast` (5.2.10)**, or
> - a `reinterpret_cast` followed by a `` `const_cast ``,
>
> **can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion.** The same semantic restrictions and behaviors apply, with the exception that in performing a static_cast in the following situations the conversion is valid even if the base class is inaccessible:
>
> - [..]

And then follows various complex rules that I can't be bothered to parse in detail.

You get the requisite warnings that it's a stupid cast, but since it's what you asked for it's what's attempted.

Compare with:

```
class Bar {};

int main() {
  Bar *b = 0;
  typedef const Bar& type;
  const type t = static_cast<type>(b);
}

// In function 'int main()':
// Line 6: error: invalid static_cast from type 'Bar*' to type 'const Bar&'
// compilation terminated due to -Wfatal-errors.
```

Comment: It's not a C style cast though, you can't write `double(0)` in C

Comment: @awoodland : The important thing is that `(T)v` and `T(v)` are semantically the same, and I'm sure we can agree the former is a cast.

Comment: @awoodland: "can be performed using the cast notation of explicit type conversion." `double(0)` and `(double)0` are both "*cast notation of explicit type conversion*". Both do exactly the same.

Comment: @ildjarn - it looks like that might be the case, but that's somewhat alarming though: I'd assumed `T(v)` always had copy constructor semantics, even for primitives - that makes "avoid C-style casts" an order of magnitude harder to spot in code.

Comment: @awoodland: Primitives don't _have_ copy constructors, so that would be rather troublesome.

Comment: @awoodland : Even for "normal", valid construction-style casts, there are three ways of doing it that are identical -- e.g., `(std::string)"x"`, `std::string("x")`, and `static_cast<std::string>("x")` are all interchangable.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - C doesn't have copy constructors either, so I'd assumed that this was the C++ way of making primitives type compatible with types that *do* have copy constructors. (For precisely where you have a `typedef` that might be `double` or `MyBigNum`)

Comment: I wish the language had an explicit `stupid_cast<T>` for that...

Comment: Some of my edits have been wrong, but since there's a good answer on the duplicate question, I cba any more :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you are casting to it.

```
class Bar {};

int main() {
  Bar *b = 0;
  typedef const Bar& type;
  const type t = b;
  (void)t;
}
```

The example above spits next error:

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'type {aka const Bar&}' from expression of type 'Bar*'
```

Comment: That doesn't explain why the cast succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that references are castable to pointers. Your expression is essentially,

```
Bar & r = reinterpret_cast<Bar&>(b);
```

But in this explicit form, I get *two* warnings:

```
warning: casting ‘Bar*’ to ‘Bar&’ does not dereference pointer [enabled by default]
warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
```

But this isn't an error, it would seem.